# How to emit an event with Vue.js inside the bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

## What I want

I'd like to emit an event if there is a request and another event if there is a response and listen to it inside my `App.vue`.

## Situation

I am using `VueResource` and the built in interceptor:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  next((response) => {
  })

})

const app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

## What I tried

### Bootstrap

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  Vue.emit('request', request)

  next((response) => {
     Vue.emit('response', response)
  })
})
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-on:request="doStuff">
    <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue___default.a.$emit is not a
>   function

---

### New App.vue after discussion

```
<template>
  <div>
     <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import EventBus from './EventBus'

  export default {
    created () {
      EventBus.$on('request', this.invokeLoading())
      EventBus.$on('response', this.stopLoading())
    },

    methods: {
      invokeLoading () {
        console.log('Start')
      },

      stopLoading () {
        console.log('Stop')
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: To emit you need a Vue instance `new Vue()` . `Vue` if console.logged is a function. So the error.

Comment: Thank you, @AmreshVenugopal! The constant app already creates a vue instance. Isn't that enough?

Comment: `EventBus.$on('request', this.invokeLoading())` please don't invoke the function. You need to pass the function as is, like: `EventBus.$on('request', this.invokeLoading)`

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! It works now :) You are my hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `eventBus` to handle this scenario like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import bus from 'path/to/event-bus'

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  bus.$emit('request', request)

  next((response) => {
    bus.$emit('response', response)
  })

})

const app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and the eventBus can be created like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default new Vue()
```

You can read more about `eventBus`es [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

The problem in your way of doing it is: `Vue` is a constructor function, it doesn't have the `emit` method on itself.

---

To listen to the emitted events in any component you need to have eventBus imported. So, assuming the app component:

```
import bus from 'path/to/event-bus'

export default {
  created () {
    bus.on('request', this.onRequest)
    bus.on('response', this.onRequest)
  },
  methods: {
    onRequest () {
      // do something.
    },
    onResponse () {
      // do something.
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the app component starts listening to both the events the moment the app component is created. You can use other [life-cycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) hooks but since these events are emitted by a separate `Vue` instance, which is `bus` you can't do something like: `<div v-on:request="doStuff">...</div>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't listen for it inside my `App.vue`, any ideas?  `<div v-on:request="dofStuff"></div>`

Comment: @Julian I'll add that part.

Comment: Very cool, it's close now ;) It is working but I get many errors after it like: _vue-resource.common.js?2f13:288 TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined_ Full image: blob:http://imgur.com/4e33b155-839b-45ea-95a3-7c9f834557d6 I also tried it with `bus.$on`.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the functions. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141404/tempwing we can discuss here.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as the chat works again I will contact you (can't login).

Comment: Oh, the image you sent doesn't open up. In that case just edit your question with app.vue

Comment: Did it, please check _New App.vue after discussion_ inside the question again.